# PHP decoding and encoding json with unicode characters

Tags: php, json, unicode, character-encoding

I have some json I need to decode, alter and then encode without messing up any characters.

If I have a unicode character in a json string it will not decode. I'm not sure why since json.org says a string can contain: `any-Unicode-character-    except-"-or-\-or-    control-character`. But it doesn't work in python either.

```
{"Tag":"Odómetro"}
```

I can use utf8_encode which will allow the string to be decoded with json_decode, however the character gets mangled into something else. This is the result from a print_r of the result array. Two characters.

```
[Tag] => OdÃ³metro
```

When I encode the array again I the character escaped to ascii, which is correct according to the json spec:

```
"Tag"=>"Od\u00f3metro"
```

Is there some way I can un-escape this? json_encode gives no such option, utf8_encode does not seem to work either.

**Edit** I see there is an unescaped_unicode option for json_encode. However it's not working as expected. Oh damn, it's only on php 5.4. I will have to use some regex as I only have 5.3.

```
$json = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string ...
```

Comment: What character set is your input in? UTF-8? Something else?

Comment: `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` is new in PHP 5.4 (i.e., it doesn't exist yet).

Comment: If you're already working with UTF-8, then you definitely don't want to use `utf8_encode`, which is designed to convert from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8. Is this string coming from a database, a string literal, or some other source? (Reason for all the questions: `json_encode` is specifically built to *only* work with UTF-8 strings).

Comment: It's coming from a postgres database, which has encoding set to UTF-8. I'm not sure why it does not parse, python won't parse it either though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Judging from everything you've said, it seems like the original `Odómetro` string you're dealing with is encoded with ISO 8859-1, not UTF-8.

Here's why I think so:

- `json_encode` produced parseable output after you ran the input string through `utf8_encode`, which converts from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8.
- You did say that you got "mangled" output when using `print_r` after doing `utf8_encode`, but the mangled output you got is actually exactly what would happen by trying to parse UTF-8 text as ISO 8859-1 (ó is `\x63\xb3` in UTF-8, but that sequence is `Ã³` in ISO 8859-1.
- Your `htmlentities` hackaround solution worked. `htmlentities` needs to know what the encoding of the input string to work correctly. If you don't specify one, it assumes ISO 8859-1. (`html_entity_decode`, confusingly, defaults to UTF-8, so your method had the effect of converting from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8.)
- You said you had the same problem in Python, which would seem to exclude PHP from being the issue.

PHP will use the `\uXXXX` escaping, but as you noted, this is valid JSON.

So, it seems like you need to configure your connection to Postgres so that it will give you UTF-8 strings. The PHP manual indicates you'd do this by appending `options='--client_encoding=UTF8'` to the connection string. There's also the possibility that the data currently stored in the database is in the wrong encoding. (You could simply use `utf8_encode`, but this will only support characters that are part of ISO 8859-1).

Finally, as another answer noted, you do need to make sure that you're declaring the proper charset, with an HTTP header or otherwise (of course, this particular issue might have just been an artifact of the environment where you did your `print_r` testing).

Comment: Thanks for the detail in your answer. It seems correct since Japanese characters are converted to \uXXXX even with `htmlentities($item, NULL, 'UTF-8');`. So I can only assume the input string is not utf-8. I've just been testing this with a simple form for now, but it seems that the pg library uses ISO string encoding.

Comment: Having the similar issue. echo prints the character right but json_encode convert `诶ó` to `\u8bf6\u00f3`

Answer (score 64):

I have found following way to fix this issue... I hope this can help you.

```
json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Good answer. Slash and UNICODE are the main two evils in JSON encode. If you handle both, it will work perfectly on 90% cases.

Comment: @Harikrishnan Where did you base the 90% on?

Comment: @Garre From my experience only. That percentage is subjected to change with different environments.

Comment: This is the way to go. In my case using these flags significantly reduced the resulting file size;

Comment: it is a perfect answer. @sunny sm

Comment: A real hero here. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks @AnjanaSilva it my pleasure. Happy to help

Answer (score 16):

[`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`](http://php.net/json_encode) was added in PHP 5.4 so it looks like you need upgrade your version of PHP to take advantage of it. 5.4 is not released yet though! :(

There is a [5.4 alpha release candidate](http://qa.php.net/) on QA though if you want to play on your development machine.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with 5.3, but I've found a way around this in my Answer below.

Answer (score 8):

A hacky way of doing JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE in PHP 5.3. Really disappointed by PHP json support. Maybe this will help someone else.

```
$array = some_json();
// Encode all string children in the array to html entities.
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key) {
    if(is_string($item)) {
        $item = htmlentities($item);
    }
});
$json = json_encode($array);

// Decode the html entities and end up with unicode again.
$json = html_entity_decode($rson);
```

Comment: This will only reliably work if your strings in `$array` are (and I do hate to keep banging the same drum) encoded with ISO 8859-1. This is, in effect, a convoluted way of converting from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8. This *would* have the effect of giving you JSON without the Unicode escape sequences, but if your input strings are UTF-8, you *need* to pass `'UTF-8'` as the charset parameter to `htmlentities` for this to work.

Answer (score 7):

```
$json = array('tag' => 'Odómetro'); // Original array
$json = json_encode($json); // {"Tag":"Od\u00f3metro"}
$json = json_decode($json); // Od\u00f3metro becomes  OdÃ³metro
echo $json->{'tag'}; // OdÃ³metro
echo utf8_decode($json->{'tag'}); // Odómetro
```

You were close, just use utf8_decode.

Answer (score 4):

try setting the `utf-8` encoding in your page:

```
header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

this works for me:

```
$arr = array('tag' => 'Odómetro');
$encoded = json_encode($arr);
$decoded = json_decode($encoded);
echo $decoded->{'tag'};
```

Comment: Good tip, but that's only half the problem. I need to encode it properly. This won't even be displayed it's purely for data manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

Try Using:

```
utf8_decode() and utf8_encode
```

Answer (score 1):

To encode an array that contains special characters, ISO 8859-1 to UTF8. (If utf8_encode & utf8_decode is not what is working for you, this might be an option)

Everything that is in ISO-8859-1 should be converted to UTF8:

```
$utf8 = utf8_encode('이 감사의 마음을 전합니다!'); //contains UTF8 & ISO 8859-1 characters;    
$iso88591 = mb_convert_encoding($utf8, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
$data = $iso88591;
```

Encode should work after this:

```
$encoded_data = json_encode($data);
```

[Convert UTF-8 to & from ISO 8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/374463/7240121)