# Arabic Characters in JSON decoding

Tags: php, json

```
$test = json_encode('بسم الله');
echo $test;
```

As a result of this code, the output is: `"\u0628\u0633\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647"` while it should be something like "بسم الله". Arabic Characters are encoded when being JSON encoded while at the Youtube API this is not the case:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/RqMxTnTZeNE?v=2&alt=json

You can see at Youtube that Arabic characters are displayed properly. What could be my mistake?

HINT: I'm working on an API< the example is just for the sake of clarification.

Comment: you can show arabic characters without using json_encode, so why do you want to try json_encode these characters?

Comment: Use Google Input Tools for arabic text

Comment: I'm working on an API, that's why I'm trying to json_encode

Comment: The output is correct. That is a UTF-8 encoded string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381900/php-decoding-and-encoding-json-with-unicode-characters

Comment: if you are using any string related functions, try to use the multibyte equivalent.. substr on arabic gave me a lot of trouble.. It took me days to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`"\u0628\u0633\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647"` and `"بسم الله"` are equivalent in JSON.

PHP just defaults to using Unicode escapes instead of literals for multibyte characters.

You can specify otherwise with [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) (providing you are using PHP 5.4 or later).

```
json_encode('بسم الله', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: My host doesn't support PHP 5.4 yet!
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Fantastic! that worked.

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct JSON encoded version of the UTF-8 string. There is no need to change it, it represents the correct string. Characters in JSON can be escaped this way.

JSON *can* represent UTF-8 characters directly if you want to. Since PHP 5.4 you have the option to set the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag to produce raw UTF-8 strings:

```
json_encode($string, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

But that is only a preference, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Both formats are valid and equivalent [JSON](http://json.org/) strings:

> ```
> char
>     any-Unicode-character-
>         except-"-or-\-or-
>         control-character
>     \"
>     \\
>     \/
>     \b
>     \f
>     \n
>     \r
>     \t
>     \u four-hex-digits
> ```

If you prefer the unencoded version, simply add the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag:

```
<?php

$test = json_encode('بسم الله', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $test;
```

This flag requires PHP/5.4.0 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as mentioned before it doesn't matter, since both strings are equivalent.
What you SHOULD do however is make sure that the encoded string is decoded before it's send to an output.

```
echo json_decode($test);
```

Or because JSON contain most likely more than just a single string:

```
$obj['arabic'] = 'بسم الله';
$obj['latin'] = 'abcdef';
$obj['integer'] = 12345;

$test = json_encode($obj);

$testobject = json_decode($test);
echo $testobject['arabic'];
```