# Dictionary giving improper value

Tags: ios, ios5, nsstring, nsdictionary

This is my code

```
for(id tempLangItem in jp.staffData)
        {
 NSMutableDictionary *temp=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:tempLangItem];
            NSString *name = [temp objectForKey:@"lang_name"];
            NSLog(@"item_name =%@",name);
            NSLog(@"value in dictionary=%@",temp);



}
```

**These are log details**

```
item_name =marinieres

 value_in_dictionary={
    "lang_id" = 2;
    "lang_name" = "\U7a46\U840a\U65afmarinieres";
    time = "2013-06-05 05:14:50";
}
```

why it is giving `lang_name=\U7a46\U840a\U65afmarinieres` in `value_in_dictionary` logs while it is displaying correct in `item_name` log.

Comment: What are the `tempLangItem`-dictionary your `temp`-dictionary are initialized with? Could you include it in you code, perhaps?

Comment: @7SLEVIN Now check my code i have made some improvements.

Comment: @7SLEVIN jp.staff data is an NSArray of NSdictionary.

Comment: Convert the string into the proper format as these are the UTF characters that are being displayed

Comment: Please find the below question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980421/arabic-characters-in-json-decoding

Comment: Is that string supposed to contain 穆萊斯 at the beginning? Note that \U expects eight hex digits and \u is used for four hex digits, which may be the reason why they’re being ignored when showing the string with `NSLog()`. Could you edit your question and show the corresponding JSON string? It could be a problem in your JSON provider or the JSON parser you’re using.

Answer (score 2):

Tried

```
NSMutableDictionary *temp=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[temp setObject:@"marinieres" forKey:@"lang_name"];

NSString *name = [temp objectForKey:@"lang_name"];
NSLog(@"item_name =%@",name);
NSLog(@"value in dictionary=%@",temp);
```

and what my log shows

```
2013-06-06 12:38:02.337 Cool[96423:11303] item_name =marinieres
2013-06-06 12:38:04.022 Cool[96423:11303] value in dictionary={
    "lang_name" = marinieres;
}
```

1 Quick question: if it is an NSDictionary why you creating a new instance?

```
 NSMutableDictionary *temp=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:tempLangItem];
```

try with `tempLangItem`

Comment: It could be anything that are coming from Jp. staffData, NSArray of NSdictionary.

Comment: why create an instance ?use the dict itself

Comment: How can i change the value of any key for NSdictionary ?

Comment: [temp setObject:@"marinieres" forKey:@"lang_name"];

Comment: setObject methode applicable for NSMutableDictionary not for NSDictionary.

Comment: Yes exactly.NSDictionary is immutable.But you need here to get the value not set right? the code seems so