# how I can send Arabic character inside json from android to PHP

Tags: php, android, json

When I create json in android then I put arabic character in json like code below:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 try {
       json.put("jsonValue", "بسم الله ");
 } catch(Exception e) {
 }
 JSONArray postjson = new JSONArray();
 postjson.put(json);

 httppost.setHeader("json", json.toString());
 httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost", postjson);             

 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The php code contains charset_utf_8 but the result is not correct.
php code is shown below

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <?php

   $json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
   var_dump($data);
   $data = json_decode($json);
   $jsonValue= $data->jsonValue;

   echo $jsonValue;
 ?>
```

The result printed like this "(3E 'DDG", could any one show help plz?

Comment: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980421/arabic-characters-in-json-decoding

Comment: i was tried it, but this dosen't change any thing @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`URLEncoder`** in android like below:

```
json.put("jsonValue",URLEncoder.encode(jsonValue, "utf-8"));
```

and in your php code use urldecode:

```
$jsonValue= urldecode($data->jsonValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode string using `URLEncoder` before sending to server

```
URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
```

You can change encoding format from UTF to other format e.g. JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE etc

Answer (score -1):

It Is Fixed by This :

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8"));
```