# json_decode($data, true); doesn't work

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to  access stock Quotes through Google Finance

by doing so:

```
$quote = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=VSE:APG1L'); 
$json = str_replace("\n", "", $quote);
$data = substr($json, 4, strlen($json) -5);
print_r($data);  
$json_output = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($json_output);  
echo "\n".$json_output['l'];
```

`json_decode` suppose to give me an normal array with keys and values, but it doesn't.

Comment: What does it give you instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `json_last_error()` after attempting `json_decode()` you'll see that you are getting:

```
JSON_ERROR_UTF8 Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

Try this:

```
$quote = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=VSE:APG1L');
$json = substr($quote, 4, -5);
$json_output = json_decode($json, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
print_r($json_output);
```

See: http://3v4l.org/jkInl

Note that `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` is only available as of php 5.4

Another option would be to do...

```
$quote = utf8_decode($quote);
```

...after you fetch it. This will convert the euro symbol into a `?` character. Might not be what you want, but at least you get json_decode to return an array to you.

**Update**: See here for more information:

[PHP decoding and encoding json with unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381900/php-decoding-and-encoding-json-with-unicode-characters)

Comment: `utf8_decode` doesn't change `€` into `\u20AC`, but into an `?`; this is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel updated answer, now preserves the € (assuming php 5.4)

Comment: I'm still working on it, so the OP doesn't need al least PHP 5.4. BTW, for me, running PHP 5.4.13, I still get a `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`.

Comment: Did you look at http://3v4l.org/jkInl? 5.4+ is looking beautiful. No JSON errors.

Comment: I've seen it. Where did you find about `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`? As far as I can see, it is only an option for `json_encode`.

Comment: It was another SO thread that mentioned JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE in a json_decode, I'll try to find it again.

Comment: thanx jszobody major problem is solved, of course it leads to the other problem which is already discussed. I will try find proper soliution for currency charachters, it would be a big improvement on my site to display stocks denominated in it's market currency

Comment: @pixelblock excellent, glad that helped. I just added a link to another SO discussion that provides further information about json encoding and unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to "manually" replace all instances of `€` by `\u20AC` (which is the unicode character point for the Euro sign).

```
$quote = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=VSE:APG1L');
$quote = str_replace(chr(128), '\u20AC', $quote);
$json = substr($quote, 6, -3); // remove unnecessary '// [ … ]'
$json_output = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($json_output);
```

Comment: That only fixes a symptom, not the problem.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: The problem *is* the JSON containing the Euro sign. `utf8_decode` converts the Euro sign into a `?`, so that's also not a solution.

Comment: Are there any other characters that may appear, with the same problems?

Comment: thanks Marcel Korpel , good approach, but it creates array within array ,that unecessery beast multidimensional array ;) http://3v4l.org/I8XBp

Comment: @pixelblock: That's just how Google sends its string, but you can of course remove the `// [ … ]` using `substr`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: I agree that there can be other characters (e.g. other currency signs) that can be sent, but we can only replace them this way with unicode character points, there is no function that does this for you. The actual problem lies at Google, that sends these malformed JSON-formatted strings.