# How to replace “¿” using str_replace() in PHP?

Tags: php, str-replace

This is the code I am trying.

```
echo str_replace("¿","","¿ teste ¿ teste");
```

I want to find the ¿ in any given string and remove it. But, this code is not working right.

What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT:

I managed using html special code;
The link:
http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a `¿` in the string you're searching (`it's Tuesday!`)

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine.

```
php -r 'echo str_replace("¿","","¿Is it Tuesday?");'
```

Output:

```
Is it Tuesday?
```

---

EDIT

You can try making sure the file itself is 100% ASCII by escaping characters:

```
<?php

$c  =  json_decode('"' . '\u00bf' . '"'); // the question mark

echo str_replace( $c, '', $my_string ) . "\n";
```

(Taken from [PHP decoding and encoding json with unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381900/php-decoding-and-encoding-json-with-unicode-characters))

Comment: That does not work here, can be some configuration of PHP?

Comment: I managed using str_replace("&iquest;", "",$_POST['objetivo']);

Answer (score 1):

You might be saving the php file with an encoding that does not correctly store your string. Save your php file using a UTF encoding and try again.

Comment: I saved the file using a UTF, it did not work.