# PHP json_encode - invalid JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-services

I created a php code to seek informations on database (mySQL) and "transform" to JSON.

The JSON output seems to be correct, but when use some validator, alway returns error: `Unexpected token`.

If I manually type the JSON output on validator, it works! If I copy and paste, exception occurs.

For verify the JSON: http://devsa.url.ph/?cod=all

```
<?php
include('connectdb.php');

$something = $_GET['cod'];
$sqlcode = mysql_query("Select descricao from Produtos Where codigo='$something'");
$sqlcode2 = mysql_query("Select descricao from Produtos");

$jsonObj = array();

if ($something == 'all') {
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($sqlcode2)) {
        $jsonObj[] = $result;
    }
} else {
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($sqlcode)) {
        $jsonObj[] = $result;
    }
}

$final_res = json_encode($jsonObj);

echo $final_res;
?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Some JSON validators require objects only. Try using json_encode with JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

Comment: (A better way is to wrap your array in an object: $final_res = json_encode(array('result' => $jsonObj));

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP decoding and encoding json with unicode characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381900/php-decoding-and-encoding-json-with-unicode-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [Byte Order Marks (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of your file.

You should save your script without a BOM as this causes your output to be invalid json.

If you look in your developers tools at the exact response, you will see two `ï»¿` sequences at the start before the json starts:

```
ï»¿
ï»¿[{"descricao":"Amendoim"},{"descricao":"Cerveja"},{"descricao":"Peixe"}]
```

You should save your script without a BOM as this causes your output to be invalid json.

Comment: @BogdanBurim I don't know about that, but it is the actual reason :-)

Comment: For resolution, I open the php file on the Notepad++. On menu Format > UTF-8 (without BOM)

Answer (score 1):

Your json starts three bytes that represent the BOM for UTF-8

EF BB BF

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Perhaps some parsers don't like those first three bytes