# How json encode arabic in laravel 5.2 json response?

Tags: php, json, laravel, character-encoding, laravel-5

My application supporting multiple language.

My Controller,

```
 public function index(Request $request) {
    return DB::table('offer_types')
                    ->join('offer_type_details', 'offer_type_details.offer_types_id', '=', 'offer_types.id')
                    ->where('offer_type_details.languages_id', $request->language_id ? $request->language_id : 1)
                    ->get();
}
```

In case of Arabic, it returns following `json`,

```
    [{
    "id": 1,
    "description": "desc",
    "offer_types_id": 1,
    "languages_id": 2,
    "title": "\u062d\u0632\u0645"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "description": "desc",
    "offer_types_id": 2,
    "languages_id": 2,
    "title": "\u0641\u0646\u0627\u062f\u0642"
}]
```

How can I encode this `arabic` value in Laravel 5.2?

Comment: That can be done by sending the following HTTP header;`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: also check with this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381900/php-decoding-and-encoding-json-with-unicode-characters

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin by mistake.. reverted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
$data = DB::table('offer_types')
                    ->join('offer_type_details', 'offer_type_details.offer_types_id', '=', 'offer_types.id')
                    ->where('offer_type_details.languages_id', $request->language_id ? $request->language_id : 1)
                    ->get();

return Response::json($data, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Or

```
return response()->json($data, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: second one worked fine.. thanks... is there any method to set globally?

Comment: What do you mean? If you're asking about `Response::`, you could try to use `\Response::`.

Comment: no.. I dont want to repeat in every controller, I am developing APIs. So is there any method to set encoding globally in application?

Comment: I think it's the easiest and more readable way to do this, but if you really want to do this globally, you could try this solution: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-prevent-laravel-from-returning-escaped-json-data

Answer (score 2):

Do JSON encode with `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag.

`json_encode($multibyte_string, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

It encodes multibyte Unicode characters literally. So the Unicode characters will not be escaped like `\uXXXX`.