# How make nice look REST API using PHP after retrieve from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, postman

I retrieved REST API from MySQL but look appears disgusting in Postman and uncomfortable for the following use.

[image]

I just begin to study PHP and can to a little bit.

My code:

```
<?php   
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***");

$sql = "SELECT `id_question`, `question`, `opt_asnwer_1`, `opt_asnwer_2`, `opt_asnwer_3`, `opt_asnwer_4`, `right_answer` FROM `questions`";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$json_array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $json_array[] = $row;
    }
echo json_encode($json_array);

?>
```

What look which I want to make. Example:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: try sending json header `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before `json_encode`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381900/php-decoding-and-encoding-json-with-unicode-characters

Comment: Very simple. Thanks!

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: you could simply use `echo` like this

    `echo '<pre>';
   print_r($your_variable);
   echo '</pre>';`

this will print the pretty way you want