# convert latin1 string to utf8 in php

Tags: php

i have this php file that connect to my MySQL BD , the BD callation is latin1_swedish_ci

this is my php code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("ttbfb", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo $row['name'];

}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

how can i convert the $row['name'] string into utf8 before i get the echo ?

Comment: what's the matter you got when `echo $row['name']`

Comment: Consider using `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")` right after connecting to your database.

Comment: @OfirBaruch i did right after mysql_select_db("ttbfb", $con); but still didnt change the string to anything

Comment: For those concerned about whether this is a duplicate, even though it seems to want to do the conversion in the opposite direction: note that the other question has "and back" in the title, which means that it is broader and covers *both* directions of conversion. Also note that the answer here simply links to the other Q&A...

Comment: how to convert "à¤¸à¥‚à¤—à¥€, à¤ªà¥‹à¤–à¤°à¥€ à¤¤à¤¹à¤¸à¥€à¤² à¤®à¥‡à¤‚ à¤­à¤¾à¤°à¤¤ à¤" characters to unicode human readable please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Options for converting encodings are provided in [Convert utf8-characters to iso-88591 and back in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/374463/120080)

- [`iconv()`](http://php.net/function.iconv)
- [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/function.mb-convert-encoding)
- [`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/function.utf8-encode) and [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/function.utf8-decode)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you are getting, and what you expect instead?

Comment: ÃÎÈÇÑ ÇáÊæÌíå ÇáÚÜÇã ááÊÑÈíÉ ÇáÈÏäíÉ Èäíä and i`m expecting arabic characters

Comment: Arabic characters encoded in latin1?