# How to convert utf-8 hindi font to english

Tags: javascript, php, api, utf-8

i want to make a voice based language translator app (eng-to-hindi).
im using google translator api for the actual translation. the problem is that google returns the translated text in utf-8 hindi font , which cant be converted to speech. 
so i need a way of converting utf-8 hindi font to english.

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374425/convert-utf8-characters-to-iso-88591-and-back-in-php

Comment: that is not the code im looking for. i want to convert hindi-to-english without translating

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "utf-8 hindi font". UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode, Hindi is a language, and a font is a particular size/style of a typeface.

Comment: Re, "i want to convert hindi-to-english without translating."  That doesn't make any sense.  You probably mean that you want to _transliterate_ the _sounds_ of Hindi speech using the _roman_ alphabet.  I've got no idea how much the written Hindi language tells you about how the words sound, but there aren't many languages for which it's an easy problem.  Using an English language text-to-speech algorithm for non-English, transliterated text probably will give you very poor results.