# latin1 to utf8 conversion issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have problem with conversion from `latin1` to `utf8`
I have got 2 databases, first is in `latin1` second in `utf8`

**Example:**
`select * from latin1_db` gives
`"SPÓŁDZIELNIA PRODUCENTÓW TRZODY ODRODZENIE BOBROWNIKI  WĄGROWIEC"`

but when i insert to utf8 db it becomes
`"SPÓ?DZIELNIA PRODUCENTÓW TRZODY ODRODZENIEBOBROWNIKI W?GROWIEC"`

how to make that both string will be same

i was using

```
$str=utf8_encode($str);  
$str=Encoding::fixUTF8($str);
```

and

```
iconv
```

but result was not good.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored and look for "question marks".  Also provide the HEX as suggested.  Do not use any "fix" routines; it only complicates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the database connection encoding with

```
SET NAMES utf-8
```

as an sql query. You don't provide the code with the database request, so i cannot update your code to illustrate what i mean. With PDO it should be

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=yourdbhost;dbname=yourdbname',
    'username',
    'password',
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
```

Comment: it gives "SPÓ?DZIELNIA PRODUCENTÓW TRZODY ODRODZENIE
BOBROWNIKI  W?GROWIEC" it doesnt change letters ł or ą

Answer (score 0):

Set database connection encoding to UTF-8.

Also have a look at this answer: [Convert utf8-characters to iso-88591 and back in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374425/convert-utf8-characters-to-iso-88591-and-back-in-php/374463#374463).

```
mb_convert_encoding();
```

Might be useful for you.